# How to Make automatic classes with algorithm in qgis modeler?

Tags: style, algorithm, classification, qgis-modeler

I have 1 column of numeric data in one attribute table of a layer made of points.

I want to regroup this data in classes (style) with the Qgis modeler and each class must have a specific lenght that i previously calculated with the modeler.

Which algorithm do i have to use in the modeler in order to create these classes automatically ?